# Change TextView Value When Click On Screen

Tags: java, android, textview

I want to make a simple counter. When i click on the screen, the value of the textvalue will increase.

So my activity.

```
public class MyTasbih extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

//Button btn;
TextView t;
int i=0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);

    //btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    t.setOnClickListener(this);

    updateCounter();

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    i++;
    updateCounter();

}

private void updateCounter() {

    t.setText(i);
}
}
```

but its crash. I'm newbie, please help.

Comment: there is a view in Eclipse called logcat. You can see there where it crashes.

Answer (score 1):

please try this and check

```
private void updateCounter() {

    t.setText(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have eclipse handy to check this but should update not be:

```
private void updateCounter() {
    t.setText(Integer.toString(i));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MyTasbih extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

//Button btn;
TextView t;
int i=0;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main6);

    //btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.t);

    //btn.setOnClickListener(this);
    t.setOnClickListener(this);

    updateCounter();

}

public void onClick(View view) {
    i++;
    updateCounter();

}

private void updateCounter() {

    t.setText(String.valueOf(i));
}
}
```